# How to enable hot reloading in mobile devices in the local network? (Django + Webpack-Dev-Server)

Tags: django, webpack-dev-server

### Question

How do you enable hot reloading of javascript content when using Django and webpack-dev-server? The ideal solution would work even if the local IP-address of the development machine changes. (which happens time to time)

---

### Current setup

I am running django by

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5555
```

And I can use a mobile phone in the same wifi to connect to the development server. I get the correct IP-address by

```
import socket
local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print('Developing locally. Access through wifi: {}:5555'.format(local_ip))
```

Which prints out something like

```
Developing locally. Access through wifi: 192.168.8.105:5555
```

Using this setup, I can see any HTML content served by django.

Then, I added a simple React component, and the django-webpack-loader (v.0.5.0). I am running webpack-dev-server using command "node server.js", with the following "server.js":

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server')
var config = require('./webpack.local.config')

var ip = 'localhost'

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  host: "1ocalhost",
  historyApiFallback: true,
  headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
}).listen(3003, ip, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  console.log('Listening at ' + ip + ':3003')
})
```

The config.output.publicPath is defined in an another file, and it is config.output.publicPath = 'http://' + ip + ':3003' + '/assets/bundles/'.

With this setup, the React component shows on the page on the development computer (at http://127.0.0.1:5555/). Also, the hot reloading works (just saving the JS-file will cause component on the web page to reload).

**However**, on mobile device in the same wifi, I can see only the HTML part, but not the React/JavaScript part. Using Google Developer tools and USB cable I can see that the mobile browser cannot access the file "`http://localhost:3003/assets/bundles/app-6d6d5c0dad55fc4b0e9e.js`" generated by the webpack-dev-server (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). How would you set this up correctly? I have also tried changing all the "localhost"-parts to 0.0.0.0, but then nothing (except the basic HTML) is shown even on the development machine.

Comment: host: "1ocalhost",  is not correct ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution (perhaps there are better ways, but this was good enough for me):

### Install internal-ip

(or any other npm package which can output your internal IP to a variable)

```
npm install --save-dev internal-ip
```

### Tell webpack-dev-server to run on local ip

```
var ip = require('internal-ip').v4()
```

(to both, `server.js` and to the `ip` in `config.output.publicPath = 'http://' + ip + ':3003' + '/assets/bundles/'`, which is defined in the `webpack.local.config`-file.). I alse removed the `host: "1ocalhost",`-line from the "server.js"-file.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the Django development server, change the `ip` variable to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. Your phone is searching for a server in the phone and failing to find it. This will set the appropriate IP address to connect to.

```
var ip = '0.0.0.0'
```

**Update:** you should try removing the `http://0.0.0.0:3003` part of your public path, leave the / at the beginning. that way, the browser will grab the bundle at whatever host the URL is pointing to.

```
publicPath: '/assets/bundles/',
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This was the answer I found in many places, but unfortunately I am developing on a Windows machine, and this does not work. With ip = `0.0.0.0` the React components wont show up even on the development machine. (it gives a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`-error for the JS bundles.)

Comment: I tried also changing the publicPath to `'/assets/bundles/'`, but now I got `GET http://127.0.0.1:5555/assets/bundles/app-87d619513edb993e5345.js 404 (Not Found)` on my dev machine.

Comment: try adding more data to your question, specially parts of the webpack config, where is the port 5555 defined?

Comment: The port 5555 is defined at the "runserver" command of django, as shown above. I actually got the hot reloading working, and could post an aswer.